# Hacer un Update con ORDER BY en PHP

Tags: php, sql

tengo otro problema al momento de querer hacer la modificación del expediente, tengo en la misma tabla los años 2016 y 2017 con los regristros que empiezan de 1 hasta ... x numero, el problema está en que los Id se repiten si el año empieza, entones yo estoy tratando de ordenarlos por fecha para que me tome el mas reciente y asi lo haga, el detalle esta en que si le digo que me actualiza por medio de IdExpediente = '" .$id; me modifica los dos años, entonces he estado pensando y creo que la solucion es decirle que los acomode por año y me actualice solo los del 2017 y no los del año pasado, les presento el codigo que he estado tratando de modificar pero la sintaxis es donde me falla, no se si puedan orientarme de como debe ir.

```
    $sql = "UPDATE tExpedientes 
  SET Descripcion='".$descripcion."', 
      Fecha='".$fecha."',
        IdEstatus='".$estado."',
      IdAutoridad='".$autoridad."',
      QuejosoNombre='".$quejosoNombre."',
      QuejosoApellidos='".$quejosoApellidos."',
      IdConceptoViolacion='".$conceptoViolacion."',
      ServidorPublico='".$servidorPublico."',
      TipoAutoridad='".$tipoAutoridad."',
      IdTipo='".$tipoExpediente."',
      IdTurnadoA='".$turnadoA."'
      WHERE IdExpediente='".$id "' ORDER BY fecha DESC, IdExpediente DESC"
    $version = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Saludos. Para próximas consultas indica mediante etiqueta qué sistema de bd usas (MySQL, T-SQL, Postgres...). Si usas MySQL, tienes la función YEAR, puedes entonces filtar por ella, agregándola el WHERE. Imagino que el año está en la columna llama `Fecha`. Entonces agregas al WHERE: `WHERE IdExpediente='".$id "' AND YEAR (Fecha)=2017...` Si no usas MySQL es posible que en los otros manejadores de BD funcione igual. **Nota importante**: Usa consultas preparadas para pasar los valores a tu consulta. Si no corres el riesgo de **Inyección SQL**.

Answer (score 0):

Pues creo que solo debrias de añadir la condicion del año:

```
   $sql = "UPDATE tExpedientes 
 SET Descripcion='".$descripcion."', 
  Fecha='".$fecha."',
    IdEstatus='".$estado."',
  IdAutoridad='".$autoridad."',
  QuejosoNombre='".$quejosoNombre."',
  QuejosoApellidos='".$quejosoApellidos."',
  IdConceptoViolacion='".$conceptoViolacion."',
  ServidorPublico='".$servidorPublico."',
  TipoAutoridad='".$tipoAutoridad."',
  IdTipo='".$tipoExpediente."',
  IdTurnadoA='".$turnadoA."'
  WHERE IdExpediente='".$id "' AND fecha = '2017' ORDER BY fecha DESC, IdExpediente DESC"
$version = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

En el query te falta poner en la condición de WHERE que los años sean iguales:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tExpedientes 
SET Descripcion='".$descripcion."', 
    Fecha='".$fecha."',
    IdEstatus='".$estado."',
    IdAutoridad='".$autoridad."',
    QuejosoNombre='".$quejosoNombre."',
    QuejosoApellidos='".$quejosoApellidos."',
    IdConceptoViolacion='".$conceptoViolacion."',
    ServidorPublico='".$servidorPublico."',
    TipoAutoridad='".$tipoAutoridad."',
    IdTipo='".$tipoExpediente."',
    IdTurnadoA='".$turnadoA."'
WHERE IdExpediente='".$id "'
    AND year(Fecha) = year($fecha)
ORDER BY fecha DESC, IdExpediente DESC"
$version = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

Asi tomara los id dela año correspondiente